# IMKClient Stall detected, *please Report* your user scenario attaching a spindump (or sysdiagnose) that captures the problem

Tags: python-3.x, sysdiagnose

I am getting the following runtime warning message in my Python program.   But I am unable to determine which code is generating it. Can anyone tell me where it originates?

I've put in print statements between my code, and where this message will pop up is not deterministic, it can appear anywhere in my program output, so I am guessing it is coming from some asynchronous thread.

> 2019-11-01 23:07:25.766 Python[6028:550777] IMKClient Stall detected,
>   *please Report* your user scenario attaching a spindump (or sysdiagnose) that captures the problem -
>   (imkxpc_selectedRangeWithReply:) block performed very slowly (4.12
>   secs).

I would happily Report it with a spindump or sysdiagnose but I see no organization to send it to.

Comment: Had this one today calling a python script from node.js. (The weirdest error ever ?). At least with a MacBook there's an option in Activity Monitor, Settings to make a spindump report. As it's about 100 pages long, it may not be very helpful though.